# CRTMP Server RTSP play to Symbian RealPlayer

Tags: symbian, rtsp, realplayer, rtmpd

CRTMP Server is great tool... Nat Traversal when client is behind router working great. 
...
Tested Android 2.2, 2.3, 4.1, RTSP streaming ok (rtmp flash also ok).

But RTSP on RealPlayer (Helix DNA 10.0 onS60) always shows 'can not play media; or 'can not connect' (connection is surely established - checked with wireshark).
...
(it is programming related problem, because i am willing to explore CRTMP code to accomplish solution)

BBC RTSP channel (wowza is behind) is showed well in symbian realPlayer, but streaming source:

ffmpeg -i rtsp://[bbc_channel_address] -c copy -f rtsp rtsp://[crtmp_server_addr]:8554/ch

... is ok for android, but not working for realPlayerS60.

Does anybody have a clue about reason?

Answer (score 1):

Having RTSP working is not enough. Different phones have different requirements in terms of A/V codecs quality. The content you want to deliver may be too high quality for that device. This assumption fits well with what you said (working on android, but not on realPlayer)

You can ask this questions over the crtmpserver's mailing list. Consult http://rtmpd.com/resources/ for details about the mailing list

Edit:
Or the codecs you try to push from crtmpserver towards the phone are not even supported, let alone hitting the quality max limit

Comment: thanks... but bbc-channel (wowza based, interleaved) is played well on s60realPlayer, and just restreamed to crtmpd (without touching codecs, same h264 baseline, same aac) ... not working. 2 public streams that i tested this way are: rtsp://media4.lsops.net/live/bbcworld1_en_medium.sdp and rtsp://217.146.95.166/live/ch32yqcif.3gp ... also tested local to stream audio only ... never managed to see/hear anything on symbian.